# Register user data to firebase using django

Tags: python, django, django-models, firebase, django-admin

I am in great trouble. I have created an app where admin creates the user and the details are send to the registered email. But now my client wants that the user created by admin be saved in firebase. I am never into firebase and also done research but could not find any resource which can solve my problem.

**Code before was**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.conf import settings
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.utils import timezone
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db import models


class UserProfile(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True)
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True,help_text=("enter the first name of user"))
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True,help_text=("enter the last name"))
  address = models.CharField(max_length=300,blank=True,null=True,help_text=("enter the address"))
  contact = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True,help_text=("enter the contact"))
  email = models.EmailField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True,help_text=("enter the email"))
  username = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True,help_text=("enter the username"))
  password = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True,help_text=("enter the strong password"))
  creation_date = models.DateTimeField(editable=False,null=True)
  last_modified = models.DateTimeField(editable=False,null=True)

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.creation_date:
      self.creation_date = timezone.now()
    self.last_modified = timezone.now()
    return super(UserProfile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


  def __str__(self):
    return (self.username)


@receiver(post_save,sender=UserProfile)
def send_user_data_when_created_by_admin(sender, instance, **kwargs):
      first_name = instance.first_name
      print('first name is',first_name)
      last_name = instance.last_name
      address = instance.address
      print('address is',address)
      contact = instance.contact
      email = instance.email
      username = instance.username
      password = instance.password
      html_content = "your first name:%s <br> last name:%s <br> address:%s <br> contact:%s <br> email:%s <br> username:%s <br> password:%s"
      from_email = settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
      message=EmailMessage('welcome',html_content %(first_name,last_name,address,contact,email,username,password),from_email,[email])
      message.content_subtype='html'
      message.send()
```

How can i save user data to firebase whenever admin creates a new user from admin panel ?

Comment: Since you already have a `post_save` signal handler you can simply add the required code there. It is too broad to explain here but you can probably use [python-firebase](https://github.com/ozgur/python-firebase).

Comment: Can you provide me a link related to this? I have never used firebase and I am complete blank.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I save data to firebase.

**First:**

Import

```
from firebase import firebase
```

connect to the **users** database

```
db = firebase.FirebaseApplication("https://yourdb.firebaseio.com/users", None)
```

Get your firebase secret and authenticate your connection (The secret is a unique key for you db)
(this is a fake key just for the example)

```
secret="adfkIDKDKkklff3777dlkdkLDLdd77RA"
auth=firebase.FirebaseAuthentication(secret,"","",True)
db.authentication = auth
```

The following I recommend you to do it in your `send_user_data_when_created_by_admin` function after the `message.send()` since its where the info you want to save is already created:

```
#let say the username is jonh45, the next line of code
#will save the value of the variable first_name in 
#https://yourdb.firebaseio.com/users/auth_info/jonh45/first_name
db.put("auth_info/"+username, "first_name", first_name)

#this will be saved to /users/auth_info/jonh45/email
db.put("auth_info/"+username, "email", email)
```

And so on...

Let me know if you need any further help

Comment: Where this all code should be ? Do i have to write these all in models.py ?

Comment: try writing it at your send_user_data_when_created_by_admin so that when it send the message.send() it also save the data to you firebase